# SQL Server Database Connection C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

To initialize the connection string, it needs to be a static string. Why that happens?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CDemoLib
{
    public class Connecting
    {
        static string conString = @"connection string here";
```

Also when I am trying to open a connection using the `conn.Open()`am getting an error saying that

> The name conn.Open() does not exist in the current context

Why that error occurs ?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CDemoLib
{
    public class Connecting
    {
         static string conString = @"connection string here";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    conn.Open();
```

Comment: It should be inside a method!

Comment: @S.Akbari, I did that and I want to call it to a different namespace and class in order to open a connection to the db. However, after creating the new object, when am trying to call the method that opens the sql connection, again am seeing the "The name conn.Open() does not exist in the current context" error message

Comment: In your code above you are calling `conn.Open();` inside the body of the *class*. That is syntactically wrong and you will get the *compile* time error you mentioned above. You need to call this inside of a *method*.

Comment: @Igor I did that and I want to call it to a different namespace and class in order to open a connection to the db. However, after creating the new object, when am trying to call the method that opens the sql connection, again am seeing the "The name conn.Open() does not exist in the current context" error

Comment: **No you didn't**. Look at your code above that you *posted in your question*. There is no method.

Comment: All 3 lines are found in `public class Connecting` <= emphasis on **class**. **There is no method in your code above**

Answer (score 2):

I have anwsered this question but i will replay it for you. 
([Connection String Is not Working Object instance reference is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581130/connection-string-is-not-working-object-instance-reference-is-null/51581687#51581687))

Put your connection string at you web.config as the foloow example:

```
<add name="MovieDB"
     connectionString="Data Source=LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet- MvcMovie;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf"     
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

to read it within your code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
    System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
    if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
    {
        connString =
            rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MovieDB"];
        if (connString != null)
            Console.WriteLine("MovieDB connection string = \"{0}\"",
                connString.ConnectionString);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No MovieDB connection string");
    }
```

The name at your web.config tag 'name'

```
<add name="MovieDB".....
```

has to be the same one from your c# code:

```
connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MovieDB"]
```

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Here a method to open it:

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection(string connString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
    }
}
```

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

Don´t forget to secure your connection string at your web.config. Please, read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx

Comment: Put your connection string at you web.config as the foloow example:

In which tag, sytstem.web, system.webServer or system.codedom ?\

Comment: Also, i've tried to put it under system.web -> httpModules, and am getting the error The conncection string attribute is not allowed.

Same for providerName

Comment: inside <configuration > tag look for <connectionStrings> tag and if you are not seeing it just add it. Please let me know with you get it done! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: I added connectionStrings, however System.Configuration.Configuration does not exists

Comment: so try this : SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString); Namespace: using System.Web.Configuration;

Comment: still WebConfigurationManager, does not exists

Comment: within your c# code are you using the Namespace: using System.Web.Configuration?

Comment: How are you doind so far ?

Comment: using System.Web.Configuration; does not exist in the namespace System.Web.

Comment: Please, go to the Reference of your project in Solution Explorer, right click and choose from the list: Assemblies > Framework the System.Web namespace. Check it and hit Ok and let me know if this resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't see Assemblies option when I right click on Reference of my project

Comment: I've found the System.Web under References, however there is no option to check it or something.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using ?

Comment: Well in this case could be a problem in adding references in your VS 2017 edition. PLease see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007007/i-cant-add-reference-in-visual-studio-2017. Let me know if this solves your problem adding references into your porject.